# NameError: name 'hxs' is not defined when using Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have launched the Scrapy shell and have successfully pinged Wikipedia.

`scrapy shell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`

I am confident that this step is correct, judging by the verbose nature of Scrapy's response.

Next, I'd like to see what happens when I write

`hxs.select('/html').extract()`

At this point, I get the error:

`NameError: name 'hxs' is not defined`

What is the problem? I know that Scrapy is installed fine, has accepted the URL for the destination, but why would there be an issue witht the `hxs` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you are using the version of Scrapy that doesn't have `hxs` on the shell anymore.

Use `sel` instead (deprecated after 0.24, see below):

```
$ scrapy shell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
>>> sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0]
u'Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia'
```

Or, as of Scrapy 1.0, you should use the Selector object of the `response`, with it's `.xpath` and `.css` convenience methods:

```
$ scrapy shell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
>>> response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0]
u'Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia'
```

FYI, quote from [Using selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1) in the Scrapy documentation:

> ... after the shell loads, you’ll have the response available as `response` shell variable, and its attached selector in `response.selector` attribute.
>   ...
>   Querying responses using XPath and CSS is so common that responses include two convenience shortcuts: `response.xpath()` and `response.css()`:
>
> `>>> response.xpath('//title/text()')`
>   `[<Selector (text) xpath=//title/text()>]`
>   `>>> response.css('title::text')`
>   `[<Selector (text) xpath=//title/text()>]`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Strange, it had +2 a few minutes ago. Looks like it got 2 downvotes then, and has only been alive for about 10 minutes...and also shows only 4 views!

Comment: @MattO'Brien this is because the person who upvoted decided to downvote instead. It's ok, it happens, an ideal case would be to get the feedback so that I can improve the answer, but it is what it is. Thank you.

Comment: Well I upvoted the answer, and my vote has since been nullified...so there are 2 quietly unsatisfied people out there...

Answer (score 0):

You should use your  `verbose nature of Scrapy's response.`

```
$ scrapy shell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

if your verbose looks like this:

```
2014-09-20 23:02:14-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-09-20 23:02:14-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2014-09-20 23:02:15-0400 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-'>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page>
[s]   response   <200 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=None>
[s]   spider     <BaseSpider 'default' at 0xb5d95d8c>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

your verbose will displays `Available Scrapy objects`

so `hxs` or `sel` depends on what you have display on your verbose. For your case `hxs` wasn't available so you'll need to use 'sel' (newer scrappy version). So for some `hxs` is ok and others `sel` is what they'll need to use

Comment: `0.14.4` is more than 2 years old, why not downgrade to `Scrapy 0.7` then? :)

Comment: yes @alecxe you right :) I shoud always use the latest version but Scrapy 0.7 that's the version I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

"sel" shortcut is deprecated , you should use response.xpath('/html').extract()

Comment: Well, even if it is deprecated it works without any problems in the shell.